# How to dereference _ref tensor type in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, reference, tensorflow, dereference

How to convert reference tensor type to value tensor type?

The only way I found is to add a zero to a tensor. Is there any convenient way?

Below `assign` is a tensor of reference type. How to get rid of `_ref`?

```
import tensorflow as tf

counter = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")

zero = tf.constant(0)
one = tf.constant(1)

new_counter = tf.add(counter, one)
assign = tf.assign(counter, new_counter) # dtype=int32_ref
result = tf.add(assign, zero) # dtype=int32
result2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(assign) # dtype=int32_ref
# result3 = assign.value() # has no attribute value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should be able to use a `tf.foo_ref`-type tensor anywhere a `tf.foo`-type tensor is expected. TensorFlow ops will implicitly dereference their input arguments (unless a reference tensor is explicitly expected, e.g. in `tf.assign()`).

The simplest way to dereference a tensor is to use [`tf.identity()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#identity), as follows:

```
counter = tf.Variable(0)
assert counter.dtype == tf.int32_ref

counter_val = tf.identity(counter)
assert counter_val.dtype == tf.int32
```

Note that this answers your question, but can have surprising semantics, because `tf.identity()` **does not copy** the underlying buffer. Therefore, `counter` and `counter_val` in the above example share the same buffer, and a modification to `counter` will be reflected in `counter_val`:

```
counter = tf.Variable(0)
counter_val = tf.identity(counter)  # Take alias before the `assign_add` happens.
counter_update = counter.assign_add(1)

with tf.control_dependencies([counter_update]):
  # Force a copy after the `assign_add` happens.
  result = counter_val + 0

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print sess.run(result)  # ==> 1  (result has effect of `assign_add`)
```

Comment: This looks expected, since behaves as any other relation in tensorflow graph. For example if one would add one instead of identity, it would still be in sync since kept by graph, right?

Comment: Adding a value to a reference tensor almost always forces a copy (like `counter_val + 0` in my example above, or `tf.add(assign, zero)` in your question). This breaks the aliasing and has - in my opinion, at least - the more intuitive semantics.